# Looking for a open source user access dashboard

Tags: user-management

I need to find something that will simplify the managing, tracking, auditing, and reporting for the following main items:

```
·          Dropbox
·          E-mail
·          Active Directory (AD)
·          Schemas
·          Servers that are not part of AD
·          Data Center physical access list
·          VPN Access list
```

Ideally I'd like to find an open source application that that I would input all employees and items and link them together to easily create reports for auditing.

Comment: I have a similar question but I never got a reply. If you find something please notify me.

Comment: I'm currently manually putting everything into a spreadsheet. I do however use Snipe-IT but that's just for physical inventory and software licensing. I'm also using Dropbox Business Admin Toolkit to get Dropbox info that can be easily exported into a csv file and powershell with all the O365/Azure modules to connect and query user accounts. Ideally it would be nice to find something that could be customized enough to be used as a web UI to the data stored in a DB to easily sort and import new data gathered using various scripts that I could write.